# Error after cordova-plugin-googlemap on gradle

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, maps

I recently took a running cordova project, with this plugins already working:

```
call-number 0.0.2 "Cordova Call Number Plugin"
com.cordova.teamViewerSDK 0.1.0 "Team Viewer SDK"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.6 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.3.3 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-file 4.0.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.6.3 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.3 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.2 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.3 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy 2.2.2 "Request Location Accuracy"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser 0.2.17 "ThemeableBrowser"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.2 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.1.8 "SocialSharing"
cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.6.0 "Toast"
cordova-universal-links-plugin 1.2.1 "Universal Links Plugin"
cordova.plugins.diagnostic 3.9.2 "Diagnostic" es6-promise-plugin 4.1.0 "Promise"
kunder-cordova-plugin-webview 2.5.1 "Cordova Second Webview"
phonegap-plugin-push 2.1.3 "PushPlugin"
```

Now I'm trying to install [cordova-plugin-google maps](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps), after installation I got this error on Android Studio:

```
Project with path ':ScreenSharingSDK' could not be found in project ':app'.
```

This is how app build.gradle looks like:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
implementation(project(path: ":CordovaLib"))
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.2"
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:26.+"
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+"
compile "com.android.support:support-v13:26.+"
compile "me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.17@aar"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1"
compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0"
// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
implementation files('src/main/libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
implementation files('src/main/libs/mtscra.jar')
implementation project(':ScreenSharingSDK')
```

}

I commented **implementation project(':ScreenSharingSDK')** ,to make sure the google maps plugin is working, but then I got this error:

```
Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.6.2.
```

This is how my **project.properties** looks like:

```
target=android-26
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2=app
cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.2
cordova.system.library.3=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
cordova.system.library.4=com.android.support:support-v4:26.+
cordova.system.library.5=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+
cordova.gradle.include.1=phonegap-plugin-push/pp-push.gradle
cordova.system.library.6=com.android.support:support-v13:26.+
cordova.system.library.7=me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.17@aar
cordova.system.library.8=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2
cordova.gradle.include.2=com.cordova.teamViewerSDK/pp-build.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.3=cordova-plugin-badge/perpetualpay-badge.gradle
cordova.system.library.9=com.android.support:support-v4:26.+
cordova.gradle.include.4=cordova-plugin-local-notification/perpetualpay-    localnotification.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.5=cordova-plugin-googlemaps/perpetualpay-tbxml-android.gradle
cordova.system.library.10=com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1
cordova.system.library.11=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1
cordova.system.library.12=com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0
```

Then I followed this logic [could not build/run after google-maps plugin installed](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native-google-maps/issues/5#issuecomment-380693358), without success.

I thought the cordova cli will take care of gradle details, how can I make this plugin work with my current environment?

```
npm Version: 5.6.0
Cordova Version: 8.0.0
Gradle version: 4.4
```

Comment: It sounds like it is looking for ScreenSharingSDK in platforms/android and it doesn't exist.  I doubt it is coming from the google maps plugin, it sounds like it would come from the Team Viewer SDK which actually uses screen sharing sdks

Comment: Yep, I just checked and the problem is almost certainly coming from `Team Viewer SDK`.  If you look at the `plugin.xml` file, you can see `<resource-file src="lib/android/ScreenSharingSDK.aar" target="lib/android/ScreenSharingSDK.aar" />` which sounds like it is missing.

Comment: Thanks [BShaps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6850443/bshaps) , for some reason after install [cordova-plugin-googlemaps](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps) , I loose references for ScreenSharingSDK, I had update my google play services, install gogole-maps and finally reinstall ScreenSharingSDK.

Comment: Awesome, good to hear you got it fixed!  That is very odd behavior by the googlemaps plugin, I wonder why it is happening.

Comment: https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/blob/master/troubleshootings/conflict_with_other_plugins/README.md

Answer (score 0):

So I finally solved this problem, for some reason after install [cordova-plugin-googlemaps](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps) , all references to [cordova-team-viewer](https://github.com/r-kitek/cordova-team-viewer) was missed.

In order to install [cordova-plugin-googlemaps](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps) I followed this steps:

1. Upgrade [Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) at Android studio SDK level.
2. Update Google Play services .gradle files.

   - platforms/android/app/build.gradle

   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:**4.0.1**'

   compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:**15.0.1**"

   compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:**26.1.0**"

   - platforms/android/build.gradle

   google()

   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:**3.1.3**'

   - platforms/android/CordovaLib/build.gradle

   google()

   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:**3.1.3**'

   - platforms/android/project.properties

   cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:**15.0.1**

   cordova.system.library.8=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:**15.0.2**

   - platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
3. Install google maps plugin, with **PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION** defined

   - cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps     --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="**your key**"     --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="**your key**" --variable PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION="**15.0.1**"
4. Reinstall cordova-team-viewer plugin

   - cordova plugin remove com.cordova.teamViewerSDK
   - cordova plugin add com.cordova.teamViewerSDK